# PHP Function variables are not working in Another PHP Functions i used global also but still FAILED

Tags: php, function, variables, global-variables

I make a 3 functions in PHP but my variables are not working inside Functions mean to say Function1 variables are not working in Function2 or in any other Function i also used global but nothing happens.

SAMPLE CODES ARE:

```
<?php

function a() {
  global $var1;
  $var1 = "I am variable 1.";
}

function b() {
  global $var2;
  $var2 = "I am variable 2.";
}

function c() {
  a();
  b();

  echo $var1 . "<br>" . $var2;
}

c();  ?>
```

I get a Error

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: var1 in C:\server\www\include\form.php on line 17
```

AND

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: var2 in C:\server\www\include\form.php on line 17
```

Need Help to how to solve this errors.

Comment: Hands off from globals! Start to think in OOP

Comment: The global statement only crafts a reference to one of the "global" variables in that very functions scope. It does not ascend them to real global variables (as in other languages).

Comment: John Conde I don't wont to start work in OOP now.

Comment: You don't have to think in terms of OOP, but you should certainly start to think in terms of functions. A function should take input parameters, and *return* the output. Don't rely on them modifying external state.

Comment: @iainn agree with you Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare global in every function:

```
<?php

function a() {
  global $var1;
  $var1 = "I am variable 1.";
}

function b() {
  global $var1;
  global $var2;
  $var2 = "I am variable 2.";
}

function c() {
  a();
  b();

  global $var1; // here is
  global $var2; // here is
  echo $var1 . "<br>" . $var2;
}

c();
```